# coverity is throwing overrun-buffer-arg issues

Tags: c, printf, buffer-overflow, coverity

coverity is throwing the following error:
overrun-buffer-arg: Calling "snprintf" with "key_name + len" and "256U" is suspicious because "key_name" points into a buffer of 256 bytes and the function call may access "(char *)(key_name + len) + 255U".

```
char key_name[256];

u_int32_t  len;
```

`snprintf(key_name+len, 256, "%s", student->name);`

Please suggest how to fix this

Answer (score 2):

If `len` is anything but 0, `snprintf` can write outside the buffer `key_name`. If `student->name` is very long, for example. Or if `len` is close to 256 or over.

Since `snprintf` was specifically designed to prevent buffer overflows, it's a very helpful warning message.

It should probably be something like this:

```
char key_name[256];
size_t len = 0;

snprintf(key_name + len, sizeof key_name - len, "%s", student->name);
```

This should work for every `0` < `len` < `sizeof key_name`. Even if `len` grows, as is typical by e.g. other `snprintf` calls, this will ensure it will not overflow the buffer.

Edit:
You should also check the return value of `snprintf` against `sizeof key_name - len`. If it's equal or larger, the student name was truncated.